# Can't get broadcasting from my ALSA to work with Icecast2 and Ices2

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, icecast

I want to make podcast on Icecast2 + ices2. My goal is to broodcast music that currently  playing in my headphones.
My sound server is Pulseaudio, sound system is Alsa.

Icecast2 and ices2 have been successfully loading and according to log, ices2 connected to Icecast2.

On Icecast admin page I see mount point from ices2. In that MP I have a widget for player, but it doesn't play nothing. When I press "||" button it changes to ">", but I hear nothing.

If I download m3u and open it in Audacious I can see "Buffering" and still hear nothing.

In the mountpoint statistics it is written, that
total_bytes_read = some kilobytes, but total_bytes_sent - is always 0.

ices2 config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ices>
    <background>1</background>
    <logpath>/var/log/ices</logpath>
    <logfile>ices.log</logfile>
    <!-- 1=error,2=warn,3=info,4=debug -->
    <loglevel>4</loglevel>
    <!-- set this to 1 to log to the console instead of to the file above -->
    <consolelog>0</consolelog>
    <!-- optional filename to write process id to -->
    <!-- <pidfile>/home/ices/ices.pid</pidfile> -->
    <stream>
        <metadata>
            <name>AlexRsk podcast</name>
            <genre>blah-blah-blah</genre>
            <description>blah-blah</description>
        </metadata>

    <input>
        <module>alsa</module>
        <param name="rate">44100</param>
        <param name="channels">1</param>
        <param name="device">pulse</param>
        <param name="metadata">1</param>
        <param name="metadatafilename">/home/alexrsk/ices2/metadata</param> 
    </input>
    
    <instance>
            <hostname>localhost</hostname>
            <port>8000</port>
            <password>bandersnatches</password>
            <mount>/alexrsk.ogg</mount>

            <reconnectdelay>2</reconnectdelay>
            <reconnectattempts>5</reconnectattempts> 

            <maxqueuelength>80</maxqueuelength>    
        </instance>

    </stream>
    
</ices>
```

Icecast2 config

```
<icecast>
    <location>Russia</location>
    <admin>your@address.com</admin>

    <limits>
        <clients>100</clients>
        <sources>2</sources>
        <threadpool>5</threadpool>
        <queue-size>524288</queue-size>
        <client-timeout>30</client-timeout>
        <header-timeout>15</header-timeout>
        <source-timeout>10</source-timeout>
        <burst-on-connect>1</burst-on-connect>
        <burst-size>65535</burst-size>
    </limits>

    <authentication>
        <source-password>bandersnatches</source-password>
        <relay-password>bandersnatches</relay-password>
        <admin-user>alexrsk</admin-user>
        <admin-password>my123pass</admin-password>
    </authentication>

    <hostname>localhost</hostname>

    <listen-socket>
        <port>8000</port>
        <bind-address>0.0.0.0</bind-address>
    </listen-socket>

    <fileserve>1</fileserve>

    <paths>
        <basedir>/etc/icecast2</basedir>

        <logdir>var/log/icecast2</logdir>
    <webroot>/etc/icecast2/web</webroot>
    <adminroot>/etc/icecast2/admin</adminroot>
        <alias source="/" destination="/status.xsl"/>
    </paths>

    <logging>
        <accesslog>access.log</accesslog>
        <errorlog>error.log</errorlog>
        <loglevel>4</loglevel> <!-- 4 Debug, 3 Info, 2 Warn, 1 Error -->
        <logsize>10000</logsize> <!-- Max size of a logfile -->
    </logging>

    <security>
        <chroot>0</chroot>
        
        <changeowner>
            <user>nobody</user>
            <group>nogroup</group>
        </changeowner>
   </security>
</icecast>
```

I have tried at this moment changing in the ices2 config, in the "module" section,

pulse to "default", "hw:0,0", hw:0,1, plughw:0,0. Result is nothing.

Output of aplay -l

```
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice №0: subdevice #0
Card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice №0: subdevice #0
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved. In my case, the crucial thing was section `<encode>` in ices config.
When I added

```
          <encode>
                <nominal-bitrate>64000</nominal-bitrate>
                <samplerate>44100</samplerate>
                <channels>2</channels>
            </encode>
```

and configured the input such way :

```
<input>
                <module>alsa</module>
                <param name="rate">44100</param>
                <param name="channels">2</param>
                <param name="device">default</param>
                                <param name="periods">0</param>
                                <param name="buffer-time">500</param>
                <param name="metadata">1</param>
                <param name="metadatafilename">/home/alexrsk/ices2/metadata</param>
 </input>
```

Then everything seems to work.